# Missing .aspx in URL in IIS 8

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, iis-8

I've set up a new server with Server 2012 R2 and IIS and published an application to a new site.  When I run the application in my development environment it shows the .aspx file extension in the URL but when I browse a published instance on the IIS server it removes the .aspx extension.

So somehow it has some sort of URL rewriting enabled out the box - how do I change this as I need it to be consistent with the development version.  I installed the URL Rewrite extension to see if somehow any rules were configured but there are no rules defined.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you have an URL Rewrite in your release configuration file, for example Web.Release.config and not in your debug configuration?

Comment: @krlzlx Afraid not but thanks for the idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this was an issue for us that we had a menu system developed that showed what page was active by highlighting the appropriate menu item based on the page name from the current page URL.  We ended up modifying our code to rather just look for .contains("pagename") without the .aspx rather than evaluating the full page name including the extension.  This works fine and we haven't been able to figure out what on earth is causing the URL to be rewritten.  None of the above answers have helped identify the issue I'm afraid.

Comment: So you still have the extension .aspx missing? Your solution, which you validated, is a bypass but does not resolve the issue you're having with the extension not showing.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure your web.config file with rewrite rule (examplePage.aspx) like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="examplePage.aspx Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*\/)*examplePage\.aspx$" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" negate="true" pattern="^POST$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent"/>
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Hi @Asif.Ali is this supposed to add the .aspx back on to the URL?  I've added it in the applciation's web.config but don't see any difference.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this behavior when creating a certain kind of web project in development. So it could be something installed that interferes. I guess you looked at the web.config already for anything, but if it is not there try the machine.config.
Also, take a look in IIS itself, what is installed when you click on the root level (the one above the website).

Comment: This is happening on our production server, on the development server it works as normal - the .aspx suffix is there but not on the production server.  I can't find anything custom installed or configured on the production server, it was a clean install.